# Google analytics experiment cuts of url

Tags: ruby, google-analytics

I would like to experiment two version of a page so I have set the variation as follows:

```
http://xxx.xxxxx.com/foo

http://xxx.xxxxx.com/foo?v=b
```

The problem is that I have many urls after the `foo` and I would like the ab test work on them too.

For example:

```
http://xxx.xxxxx.com/foo/id/:id
```

How do I prevent the GA to cut of the urls after the foo and include the ab test on them too ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2664470?hl=en

Using a relative url solved my issue